# JSON.net Awaitable Async methods in WindowsStore Application

Tags: .net, json.net, async-await

I like to use the json.net serializer in a windows 8 app.

Arent there any awaitable async methods?

In normal .net 4.5 applications I have async method but not in windows store projects..

Bug ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Assuming you're using JSON.NET from NuGet, it's possible that you're getting the wrong version of the package, because the version for WinRT is specified as `winrt45`, when [it seems it should be `netcore45` or `windows8`](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Common_Framework_and_Profile_Targeting_Examples).</s> Based on the comment below, the above is most likely wrong.

But even if you fixed that, there is no point in using the `SerializeObjectAsync()` and `DeserializeObjectAsync()` methods. [All they do is wrapping the synchronous version in `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/68eacc480b484e6a3f0c9ccf921a06e1a679ff21/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs#L819)

So, to get the exactly same effect, you can just call the synchronous version from inside `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.

For more information why this pattern should not be used, see Stephen Toub's article [*Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

Comment: So it wasn't a problem with the NuGet package? How did you fix it?